# On the top left bar I am not allowed to enter the name

Tags: unity

I own Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Unity Desktop. I would like to know if it is possible for my name to appear in the top bar as in previous versions. At the moment even with Unity Tweak Tool I have not succeeded. Are there any bugs that I am not aware of? Thank you

Comment: Unity was not the default desktop for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, thus it came with 3 years of supported life. I'd suggest *release-upgrading* to 20.04 if you wish to keep using Unity 7, or you can switch to the GNOME (default) desktop which has 5 years of supported life for 18.04 (no desktop or server also had 5 years of supported life). You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to check which packages are no longer supported (those also used by Ubuntu Desktop (GNOME) will still be supported).

Answer (score 0):

In 16.04 LTS it was possible by

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true
```

but it will not work on 18.04 LTS because of the [bug 1697412](https://pad.lv/1697412) in *indicator-session* or Unity<>systemd internals. Possible alternative maybe installation of `ayatana-indicator-session`, but it does not work on Unity.

So I would recommend to install Ubuntu MATE on top of your existing system by `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^`, select MATE session on login, and then switch MATE Panel layout to Mutiny to get something like shown below:

[image: Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS]

Comment: Thanks for your availability. You offered me a solution (Mate's) that I didn't know about

Comment: However I wanted to know if this problem also exists in ubuntu version 20.04 with unity

Comment: Unfortunately the name is not shown on 20.04 LTS Unity too.

Comment: Thanks again...